# Alexa keeps asking for account linking

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit, spring-oauth2

I've got an alexa skill configured with Auth Code Grant account linking.

After the user token expires, alexa asks again for account linking and, as far as I understand from all the setup, Alexa should renew the token form my oauth server.

any ideas would help.
thanks

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: nope... and have more on that... I've added the refresh token to my spring-security config and it seems like alexa never refreshes it, so it keeps asking for granting an account link

Comment: Is the skill getting disabled as well? How long does it take to ask for re-linking?

Comment: Depends on the lifetime I config for the access token. Boss wants it for demo-ish presentations but if we go pub on this we cannot stand having this not working

Comment: We have queried customer support regarding this. Please post what was the problem once you solve it. Will do the same

Comment: Hey did you contact support about alexa not refreshing it? They said it's issue on our end but we don't think so.

Comment: @eduyayo This still doesn't seem fixed. I am struggling as well with the tokens and the alexa node sdk. The refreshToken stays undefined.

Comment: I haven't been assigned again to this stuff at the office but I asume it's got something to do with our backend as follows from the other comments. Maybe we're not supporting their login scheme or the like...